# C how to check and point a '0' in a int number

Tags: c, search, position, int

Imagine we've got an `int number = 1040` or `int number = 105` in a C program, and we want to know if this number contains a 0 and in which position/s are they. How could we do it?

Examples

1040 -> position 0 and 2.

1000 -> position 0, 1 and 2.

104 -> position 1.

56 -> NO ZEROS.

Thanks!

Comment: The purpose of SO is not to do your thinking for you, but rather a place for questions and answers about *specific* programming problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would convert it to a string; finding a character in a string is trivial.

As a rule of thumb, if you are doing maths on something, it's a number; otherwise, it's probably (or should be treated as) a string.

Alternatively, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int input=1040;
    int digitindex;
    for (digitindex=0; input>0; digitindex++) {
        if (input%10==0) {
            printf("0 in position %i\n",digitindex);
        }
        input/=10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This basically reports if the LAST digit is 0, then removes the last digit; repeat until there is nothing left. Minor modifications would be required for negative numbers.

You can play with this at http://ideone.com/oEyD7N

Comment: I don't see any conversion to string !!

Comment: I gave two possible answers for this; the first is to convert it to a string (the implementation details for which are left to the reader); the other is to do modulus (`%`) and divide, an implementation of which is shown.

Answer (score 1):

I would divide by 10 and check the remainder. If remainder is 0, then last position of the number is 0. Then repeat the same step until number is less than 10

```
#include<iostream>   

int main(void)
{
long int k = 6050404;
int iter = 0;
while (k > 10) {
    long int r = k % 10;
    if( r == 0) {
        std::cout << iter << " ";
    }
    k = k / 10;
    iter++;
}
}
```

Comment: you will find positions in inverse order, i.e `1305 ==> position 1` how u consider this ?

Comment: answered above with an example

Comment: Oh sorry i re-checked the question , yes you doing right